# How to open form action submit in the in app browser?

Tags: javascript, android, ionic-framework

I am using the Ionic app to build an android application.

I have a html form with hidden elements which I submit through javascript (by simulating a hidden submit button click).

This redirects to the payment gateway page.

Here is whatt I need to achieve:
Keeping the HTML form as it is, I need to open the url specified in the form action in the Ionic in-app browser.

I have two constraints:

1. I must use the HTML form and form action.
2. I am using websockets, hence I need to open an in-app browser so that the socket connection can remain open in the background.

Below is the code:

HTML form:

```
<form action='https://secure.payu.in/_payment' method="POST">
  <input type="hidden" name="firstname" id="payu_data.firstname" ng-model="payu_data.firstname"/>
  <input type="hidden" name="surl" id="payu_data.surl" ng-model="payu_data.surl">
  <input type="hidden" name="furl" id="payu_data.furl" ng-model="payu_data.furl">
  <input type="hidden" name="phone" id="payu_data.phone" ng-model="payu_data.phone"/>
  <input type="hidden" name="key" id="payu_data.key" ng-model="payu_data.key"/>
  <input type="hidden" name="hash" id="payu_data.hash" ng-model="payu_data.hash"/>
  <input type="hidden" name="service_provider" id="payu_data.service_provider" ng-model="payu_data.service_provider"/>
  <input type="hidden" name="txnid" id="payu_data.txnid" ng-model="payu_data.txnid"/>
  <input type="hidden" name="productinfo" id="payu_data.productinfo" ng-model="payu_data.productinfo"/>
  <input type="hidden" name="amount" id="payu_data.amount" ng-model="payu_data.amount"/>
  <input type="hidden" name="email" id="payu_data.email" ng-model="payu_data.email"/>
  <!--<input type="hidden" name="udf1" id="payu_data.udf1" value="buy_subscription" />-->
  <input type= "submit" value="submit" id="id_payu_submit_button" hidden>
</form>
```

Javascript:

```
// submit payu form
            document.getElementById("id_payu_submit_button").click();

            // initiate websocket
            var socket = DOMAIN.socket + API_URLS.billingInitiationSocket;
            var connection = new WebSocket(socket);

            // When the connection is open, send some data to the server
            connection.onopen = function () {
              // Send the message 'Ping' to the server
              connection.send(userService.userSession.user_data.token); 
            };

            // Log errors
            connection.onerror = function (error) {
              console.log("Error in initiating billing socket: " + error);
            };

            // Log messages from the server
            connection.onmessage = function (e) {

              console.log('Server: ' + e.data);              
              var data = JSON.parse(e.data);
              console.log("Websocket received data: " + JSON.stringify(data));

              if (data.hasOwnProperty("redirect") && data.redirect===true){
                $state.go("app.home");
                alert("Something happened!");
              }

            };
```